# SSL pinning with *.appspot.com: How can I know when Google is going to change their public key?

Tags: google-app-engine, ssl, openssl, ssl-certificate

I have an iOS app that is about to go live in the App Store that uses Google App Engine as its server backend. Bundled in the app binary is the *.appspot.com. wildcard certificate to allow me require SSL pinning of any HTTPS connection using the bundled certificate's public key. This helps prevent man-in-the-middle attacks on my client/server communication.

When I set this up, I knew that Google cycled their *.appspot.com. certificates every month or two. However, I was expecting appspot.com to use the same public key from month to month so that communication between my app and server wouldn't be broken.

However, in the latest certificate, without any warning, Google has changed their public key. Now my app is DOA as far as communicating with my server goes. Am I wrong to have tried to use SSL pinning with the *.appspot.com. certificate? Does Google notify developers when they are going to change their public key? Should I be using my own certificate with a custom domain instead?

Comment: This question appears to belong on another site in the Stack Exchange network because its not about programming or development. Perhaps you should try [Information Security Stack Exchange](http://security.stackexchange.com/).

Answer (score 6):

In an interesting coincidence, I've just done a first pass of editing on a future blog post about pinning (among other responsibilities I curate Cloud tech support blog posts) so there is absolutely **no** doubt on my mind about this:

> Am I wrong to have tried to use SSL pinning with the *.appspot.com.
>   certificate?

Yep.

> Does Google notify developers when they are going to change their
>   public key?

Nope, whence the above.

> Should I be using my own certificate with a custom domain instead?

Yes, exactly.  More generally, pinning only to public keys **you** control is a best-practice.

Other advice from that future blog post: a certain fraction of your app's users just won't update -- so how you can ever do any **rotation** of your pin-set?  If e.g 5% of your users don't update, are you OK with cutting them off?  The blog's advice is to have the app bypass its own pinning checks if it knows it's too old -- say, if system time is at least six weeks later than the build-time baked into the app at compile time; at least, this way, the non-updater "bricking" is temporary, not permanent...

Comment: if you need someone to help with a technical edit on your blog post, then please let me know if I can assist. I've been using pinning as a security control for years. I'm also very familiar with Gutmann's [Engineering Security](https://www.cs.auckland.ac.nz/~pgut001/pubs/book.pdf). I'm not sure this is a good strategy: *"The blog's advice is to have the app bypass its own pinning checks if it knows it's too old..."* Defend, don't ask (see Gutmann's book). noloader, gmail account.

Comment: As a matter of interest, it appears that `Public-Key-Pins` is stripped from AppEngine response headers, as reported in https://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/issues/detail?id=12694 (which issue I have verified for my own apps).  It may be possible to white-list the header (as it is with HSTS), but in any case I could find no official comment on the policy.

Comment: ... HPKP, like HSTS, can be white-listed.

Answer (score 3):

> How can I know when Google is going to change their public key?

Google does not change their public key unless something goes wrong. So you *should* pin the public key.

What the security community has found is key continuity is an important property given all the failures in practice. So some in the security community are moving away from key rotation in favor of key continuity.

Google uses short-lived end-entity/server certificates (30 days or so) to keep CRLs small (especially important for mobile clients). So you *should not* pin the certificate.

---

> However, in the latest certificate, without any warning, Google has changed their public key

That's odd, given what I know. What public key changed? Was it the Google CA (Google Internet Authority G2), the public CA (GeoTrust Gobal CA), or the end-entity certificate?

You can read more about Google's position on pinning at [Android 4.2 and Pinning](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/android-security-discuss/9YmL5-6avEg/Q2D3qPfO904J). Some of the Google security engineers provided their knowledge and opinions on it.

---

> Now my app is DOA as far as communicating with my server goes. Am I wrong to have tried to use SSL pinning with the *.appspot.com. certificate?

I don't think you were wrong to use pinning. I suspect the problem has something to do with the wild carded certificate or perhaps the upcoming [Public Key Pinning Extension for HTTP (HPKP)](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-ietf-websec-key-pinning).

Wildcard certificates are prohibited by the [CA/B Forums](https://cabforum.org/) (which documents browser policies and procedures) at the EV level, and Google is a member of the CA/B (browsers follow the CA/B Forum, and not the IETF like many suspect).

Did Google provide a rollover by way of the HPKP headers? (In reality, network-level SST/TLS pinning should *not* depend upon application-layer HPKP headers).

---

Now here's some back story... The IETF will be releasing the [Public Key Pinning Extension for HTTP](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-ietf-websec-key-pinning) RFC shortly. The changes made may help align with the RFC and the  HPKP headers. So in this case, the browsers went to the IETF for standardization rather than the CA/B which documents policies and procedures.

I feel there's a bunch of problems with the RFC, though. I feel you should not depend on it as a security control because:

- it accommodates interception due to overrides
- it lacks reporting of broken pinsets

Some of it is due to the use of an incompatible security model, and some of it is due to philosophy. The security model being used has gaps that can't be reconciled due to W3C Design Principals (in particular, see [Priority of Constituencies](http://www.w3.org/TR/html-design-principles/#priority-of-constituencies)).

You can read more about my dissention on the IETF mailing list at [Comments on draft-ietf-websec-ke​y-pinning](http://www.ietf.org/mail-archive/web/websec/current/msg02280.html).